# conversion from to non-scalar type requested ( functional )

Tags: c++, functional-programming

```
bool blur( ... ) {} 

void Effects::genQueue(std::queue<std::function<bool()> > q, std::function<unsigned()> dice){
   std::vector< std::function<bool()> > funcs;
   funcs.push_back( blur );
}
```

I am trying to make a vector of functions, "blur" being one of the functions, and I can not figure out what is wrong with this piece of code.

```
Error : "error: conversion from 'void (*)(std::queue<std::function<bool()> >, std::function<unsigned int()>)'
to non-scalar type 'std::function<void()>' requested"
```

What is this conversion that is being requested and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please post a test-case, i.e. a minimal code sample that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is this conversion that is being requested?

The error is quite clear: `blur` takes two parameters, so can't be converted to a function that takes no parameters. (At least, the error message implies that it takes two parameters; the declaration you've posted implies that it's variadic. I assume the error comes from your real code, and the `...` is just to make the question harder).

> how do I fix it?

Without knowing what you want to do with these functions, it's hard to say. Perhaps you could change `blur` so that it takes no parameters; or perhaps you could change the function type to something compatible with `blur`; or perhaps you could bind arguments to `blur`:

```
funcs.push_back(std::bind(blur, something, something_else));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have added the proper arguments allowing the code to compile. Thank you.